# Simulink-Matlab: Android audio capture

Tags: android, matlab, audio, simulink, microphone

I want to realize an Android app that captures audio from microphone of mobile device with Simulink.
I created following model in Simulink:

[image]

But I can not indicate the time (in seconds) to capture and when the recording starts.
How can I do this? I try change options of blocks but it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways can be changing the amount of samples you need. So let's say your microphone is recording at 48 kHz (standard for audio for videos). That means every second 48000 samples are being recorded by the microphone.

Let's say that you need to have the data recorded for 2 seconds. In that case, you can program to take in just 96000 samples - which can be done using a for loop.

```
samples = 48000 * 2;
for i = 1:samples
    record(); %your recording function
end
```

For loop can be implemented both using an s-block (https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/s-function-concepts.html) or by using a for iterator (http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/toolbox/simulink/slref/foriterator.html).